# How to get the spring bean object in Activiti JavaDelegate class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, activiti

I want to access a Spring bean object into the class which implements JavaDelegate interface of Activiti BPM.

When I am trying to access it, found it as "null".

The code is:

```
@Service("tempService")
public class TempServiceImpl {

    public void getData(String userName) {
        System.out.println("Data get for the user is => "+userName);
    }
}
```

JavaDelegate class is:

```
@Component
public class DataService implements JavaDelegate {

    @Autowired
    private TempServiceImpl tempService;
    
    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) {
        VariableInstance instance = execution.getParent().getVariableInstances().get("info");
        User user = (User) instance.getValue();
        System.out.println("Name: "+user.getUserName());
        tempService.getData(user.getUserName());
        System.out.println("Working fine....");
    }

}
```

When I run the application, the object "tempService" in DataService class is found "null".

Any pointer, how to fix it?

Thanks,

Atul

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, the fix is to change the setting in BPM by changing the task type to "Delegate expression" for the class "DataService" instead of "Java class".

[image]

There might be other way too but this is how I solve the issue.

Thanks,

Atul